# Files Uploaded to Filestack are not visible on S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, filestack

I am using `FileStack Javascript SDK` to upload files to My `S3 Bucket`. In FileStack developer's portal, I added my Amazon Account's dtails i.e Access ID, Access Key, Bucket Name & Bucket Path & then I used following script to upload files:

```
const client = filestack.init('MY-FILESTACK-API-KEY'); 
let options = {
  "displayMode": "overlay",
  "container": ".picker-content",
  "maxFiles": 4,
  "accept": [
    "image/jpeg",
  ],
  "storeTo": {
    "container": "MY-BUCKET-NAME",
    "path": "https://s3-MY-BUCKET-REGION.amazonaws.com/MY-BUCKET-NAME",
    "region": "MY-BUCKET-REGION",
    "disableKey": true,
  },
  "fromSources": ["local_file_system"],
  "uploadInBackground": false,
  exposeOriginalFile: true,
  onFileSelected: onFileSelect,
  onUploadDone: function(){
    console.log('upload done');
  },
}

$("#filestack-picker-btn").click(function(){
  picker = client.picker(options);
  picker.open();
});
```

Now, Code runs successfully & I can see uploaded files in FileStack **CONTENT BROWSER** area but when I go to my S3 bucket. I can't see any file uploaded there.

I want to use FileStack only to upload files in my S3 bucket & not in FileStack's Internal Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `location: s3` in `storeTo` dictionary (https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickerstoreoptions.html#location).